# Common way to iterate an object that's either a Collection or an array

Tags: java

For the code below:

```
if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(object)) {
  int index = 0;
  for (Object item : (Collection) object) {
    doWork(index);
  }
} else if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
  int index = 0;
  for (Object item : (Object[]) object) {
    doWork(index);
  }
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Is there a concise way to combine the two blocks together so I only need one if-block for handling Collection and array? The only reason I have the the if-block ***and*** the else-if-block is because I have to cast `object` to either `Collection` or `Object[]` depending on its type.

Comment: you could also overload the method with one having a parameter `Object[]` and one with `Collection`.

Comment: @KevinEsche: How does that help with not duplicating the *loop*?

Comment: Glide - Your `for` loops above are a bit odd, they never use `item` and reuse an `index` that never changes. Obviously this is just representative code, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built in. The compiler emits different code for the enhanced `for` loop when dealing with an `Iterable` vs. dealing with an array.

Either

1. Duplicate the loop (naturally the *contents* of the loop need not be duplicated; use a method as shown in the question), or
2. Wrap the `Object[]` in a `List<Object>`, for instance via [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), or
3. Create your own `Iterable` wrapper for `Object[]` (with associated `Iterator`). (Not particularly difficult, `Iterable` only has one non-default method, `Iterator` only two.)

Here's an example of #2:

```
Collection<Object> objectCollection = null;
if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
    objectCollection = (Collection<Object>) object;
} else if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
    objectCollection = Arrays.asList((Object[]) object);
} else {
    // do something else
}
if (objectCollection != null) {
    int index = 0;
    for (Object item : objectCollection) {
        doWork(index); // See note on question, slightly odd not using `item` here
                       // and not incrementing index in loop
    }
}
```

---

Side note: You were missing `.getClass()` in `if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {`.